# Push data to websocket with Reactive Spring and WebFlux

Tags: java, websocket, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to send data to a JS client but for some reason no `.textMessage` method works nor and it looks like the user just disconnects, i got the `return Mono.zip(inputMessage, outputMessage).then();` from the reactive docs. The basic idea is to send a message when something is published on redis, but i can't even connect and recieve messages properly from the WebSocket.

```java
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
        HttpHeaders headers = webSocketSession.getHandshakeInfo().getHeaders();
        final String proxyIp = headers.getFirst("x-forwarded-for");
        final String remoteIp = headers.getFirst("x-real-ip");
        final String ip = (proxyIp == null || proxyIp.isEmpty()) ? remoteIp : proxyIp;
        String rawCookieHeader = headers.getFirst("cookie");
        if (rawCookieHeader == null) {
            webSocketSession.textMessage("Missing cookie header");
            // return webSocketSession.close(CloseStatus.PROTOCOL_ERROR);
        }

        final Map<String, String> cookieMap = new HashMap<>();
        CookieParser parser = new CookieParser(rawCookieHeader);
        parser.iterator().forEachRemaining(cookie -> cookieMap.put(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue()));

        String userId = cookieMap.getOrDefault("userId", "");

        // Handle too many sessions open
        RedisAtomicInteger numberOfOpenWebSockets = getUserWebsocket(userId, chatCode);
        if (numberOfOpenWebSockets.get() >= 3) {
            webSocketSession.textMessage("Too many websocket connections opened by this account");
            return webSocketSession.close(CloseStatus.SERVICE_OVERLOAD);
        }

        Mono<Void> outputMessage = webSocketSession
                .send(messageDirectProcessor.flatMap(JsonConverter::toJson).map(webSocketSession::textMessage)
                        .doOnError(e -> log.info("Error Occurred while sending message to client.", e)));

        // When a user sends a message
        Mono<Void> inputMessage = webSocketSession.receive()
                .flatMap(msg -> redisGlobalPublisher.processMessage(msg.getPayloadAsText(), userId, ip, sessionId))
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> {
                    log.info("User '{}' Disconnected. Connections: {}, Active Users: {}", userId,
                            numberOfOpenWebSockets.incrementAndGet(), activeUserCounter.incrementAndGet());
                }).doOnError(throwable -> log.info("Error Occurred while sending message to Redis.", throwable))
                .doFinally(signalType -> {
                    log.info("User '{}' Disconnected. Connections: {}, Active Users: {}", userId,
                            numberOfOpenWebSockets.decrementAndGet(), activeUserCounter.decrementAndGet());
                }).then();

        return Mono.zip(inputMessage, outputMessage).then();
    }
```

Client is super simple:

```
        const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8082/ws")
        ws.onopen = (e) => {
          console.log(e);
          //@ts-ignore
          this.connectedToWebSocket = true;
          // console.log(JSON.stringify({"command": "subscribe","identifier":`{\"channel\":\"MESSAGE-${cookies.get('userId')}\"}`}));
          // ws.send(JSON.stringify({"command": "subscribe","identifier":`{\"channel\":\"MESSAGE-${cookies.get('userId')}\"}`}))
          console.log("Successfully connected to the echo websocket server...")
        };
        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
          console.log(event);
        }
        ws.onclose = (e) => {
          console.log(e);
        };
        ws.onerror = (e) => {
          console.log(e);
        }
```

I'm totally lost as to why the input and outputMessage are not pushed properly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: the code looks fine, nothing obvious, have you verified that you can even connect to the server, what does your debug logs say? is your code even called, does your logstatements get called on subscribe etc?

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, not much, it sends a disconnect event immediatly after connecting without sending any other message.

Comment: Actually it stays connected but no message is received on the client at all.

Comment: Pls post your full debuglogs, and also the client code

Comment: Thanks for replying, seems like i got it connected properly, but what i'm trying to do is to send a message to a specific websocket session when a redis message is published, and i'm having a hard time getting the specific session and not sending it to all clients.

Client code is nothing complex, a simple `const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8082/ws")` and then the usual `ws.onmessage = (event) => {console.log(e)}`, also `onopen` and whatnot.

Comment: I'm sorry it's hard to explain, the code is almost the same as here: https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-redis-websocket/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rawsanj/handler/ChatWebSocketHandler.java whereas in this chat app on `sendMessage` it's sent to ALL CLIENTS and not that specific session.